# Send formatted text in Skype for Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, skype, text-formatting

Is it possible to use formatting (italics, bold, preformatted) in Skype for Linux as it is on Windows? How?

I'm running Skype 4.3.0.37 on Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: Sometimes it amazes me the odd things people need to do. You can't link to an outside source. Like Google Docs?

Comment: The idea is just to use **simple** formatting to put _emphasis_ in a message, or sometimes even sending an inline block of `code` -- pretty much like you would do in a SE comment ;-). You can do it in Skype for Windows, so can you on Linux?

Comment: I would assume you'd do it the same way as windows. If it's not there then you likely can't. Also what I was saying is why you need to do that?

Comment: It does not work in the same way as windows, but the client is very different too. However I found [someone looking for a programmatic way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30303770/skype-java-api-linux-send-html-formatted-message) of doing the same who mentioned using `<pre>` tags on Linux, which is different from Windows. However this does not work for me.

Comment: If you want to be really concrete concerning the _why_, at the time I asked the question I just wanted to share a small piece of code with my colleagues without it being scrambled by smileys. I find pastebin a bit of overkill for such cases.

Comment: Gotta love dem smileys. But yeah. Paste bin is still your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the following?

> then hold control-shift and then send the message

The way that is listed in [someone looking for a programmatic way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30303770/skype-java-api-linux-send-html-formatted-message).

I did it well in this way.

Comment: Well, yes of course, when reading that question :-) However the formulation is a bit strange: it just means pressing ctrl+shift+enter, right? That does not work for me…

Comment: Yes, `pressing ctrl+shift+enter`, right. I'm running Skype 4.3.0.37 on Ubuntu 15.04, too. I inputted the text `<b>message</b>`, and pressed `ctrl+shift+enter` key. then in the side that received a message, a letter became the bold-face (this skype is running in windows), However the side where I sent a message to was displayed without becoming the bold-face (but tag `<b>`  was not displayed).

Comment: Possibly it may be that Skype on Ubuntu Can't display a message in formatted text.

Comment: I just understood that the `ctrl+shift+enter` trick only works when first sending the message. I was always trying by editing existing messages (to avoid disturbing others) and that does not work. And as you said the formatting is not displayed locally, the tags are simply removed. Similarly to the Windows client, the tags are thus lost when editing a message (but they cannot be re-added).

Comment: I see! It was such a thing. I'm glad that it became clear.

Comment: I think it would be nice to include those details in your answer but I don't want to change it too much.